# disable script for mobiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

HI friends I have to disable script for parallax effects when open on mobile phones.
I found a script similar to what I wanted and adapted, however it does not work. Anyone know what's wrong?

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if( !isMobile.any()){
    $(window).stellar(): false;
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you think `$(window).stellar(): false;` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if( !isMobile.any()){
    $(window).stellar(): false;
    }
});
```

That third line is syntactically wrong. What exactly are you trying to achieve with something like
`fn(): false;`?

I believe you're looking for:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if( !isMobile.any() ){
        $(window).stellar();
    }
});
```

In other words: only if `!isMobile.any()` should `$(window).stellar()` be executed. In the other case (where `isMobile.any()` is `true`), the `if` block should not be executed.

Answer (score 2):

What is the `: false` after `$(window).stellar()`? I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, or if it's just some kind of copy/paste error or something, but that will give:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I think you want this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if( !isMobile.any()){
       $(window).stellar();
    }
});
```

Comment: I want isdisable, not enable.

Comment: What? I assumed that calling `.stellar()` would enable your parallax effect, and that therefore you only want to call that function if you are not on a mobile platform. Is that not the case?

Comment: i need disable when it is mobile .stellar()

Comment: Right. So you accepted a later answer with identical code to mine.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the console in your browser.

Go to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyPjx/

You will see the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

The error will point to the line

```
$(window).stellar(): false;
```

Looks like you were trying to use a ternary operator but you are not?

It should be just

```
$(window).stellar();
```

If you were going the ternary route it would have been

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var hasRun = !isMobile.any() ? $(window).stellar() : false;    
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    }
};
var any=(isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if(!any){
        alert('No mobiles');
        $(window).stellar();
    }
});
```

Comment: You commented out the problem! Why did you moved code out of the namespace! That was not the issue!

Comment: `if(!any)` won't work. You mean `if(!any())`. (Though as epascarello said, that function wasn't the issue.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Here any is like a variable it can be used like `if(!any)`. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept of assigning a function to a variable. But if you want to _invoke_ the function you still need parentheses as in `if(!any())`. If you say `if(!any)` that will test whether the variable itself is falsey, which it never will be if it references a function. (Test your code and see...) Note also that in this case `any` doesn't need to be a function because you removed it from the `isMobile` "namespace", so you can just say `var any = isMobile.Android() || etc`.