# Disable jQuery for mobile devices

Tags: jquery, mobile

I would like to disable part of my jQuery script for mobile devices, heres the code I'd like to disable:

```
$('#inner-slide1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
});

$('#inner-slide2').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
});

$('#inner-slide3').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
});

$('#inner-slide4').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
});

$('#inner-slide5').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
});
```

Grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're repeating a function 5 times when you need only do it once if you just give those elements a class (I'm going for `.inner-slide`):

```
var isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? true : false;

$('.inner-slide').click(function(e) {
    if(!isMobile) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        goToByScroll(dataslide);
    }
});
```

The if statement will only result to true on a mobile device (Android,webOS,iPhone,iPad,iPod,Blackberry)

**And please note that**

```
$(this).attr('data-slide');
```

Can also be written as:

```
$(this).data('slide');
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this worked. And yes you're right, I added a class.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ use the JS code to detect if mobile - very comprehensive detection... will require a bit of modification as their function will redirect... but should be easy to do :)

Also here is another good answer from here: [disable script for mobiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918369/disable-script-for-mobiles)

Answer (score 0):

You may try

> MatchMedia.js

There is details on https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js

You can load the plugins according to the certain viewport size.