# jQuery disabled on mobile only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a jQuery function disabled on a mobile version, I followed the instructions -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104469/disable-jquery-for-mobile-devices)

However it doesn't work, here is my code:

```
var isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? true : false;
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
 jQuery("body").mousemove(function(e) {
  if(!isMobile) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('.nk-navbar-default');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
  }
 jQuery(".nk-navbar-default").css( "opacity", "0.8");
  setTimeout(function(e){
  jQuery(".nk-navbar-default").css( "opacity", "0");
  }, 2000);
 });
});
```

Best!

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue... Here is the solution (wrong condition):

```
var isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? true : false;
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
 jQuery("body").mousemove(function(e) {
  if(!isMobile) {
   jQuery(".nk-navbar-default").css( "opacity", "0.8");
   setTimeout(function(e){
    jQuery(".nk-navbar-default").css( "opacity", "0");
   }, 2000);       
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Unsolicited advice: your ternary conditional is redundant. The `test` function already returns the boolean you need: `var someBool = /foo/i.test(bar)`.